# Compilation error using Eigen library

Tags: c++, c, compilation, eigen

I'm trying to use the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) C++ template library for linear algebra, I compiled and installed the library to the following path `/usr/local/include`

I took a sample code from their site and I tried to compile with and without the `-l` option.

```
g++ -l /usr/local/include/eigen3 test.cpp -o mytest
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
test.cpp:2:23: fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory
```

How can I include this library?

Comment: Add your #include(s) code here and find where is the file you are want to include

Comment: Simple error, the web site says I (capital i) you've written l (small L).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `-I` option, not `-l`

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include/eigen3 test.cpp -o mytest
```

Comment: You don't need to link to the library. Eigen is a headers-only library.

Comment: @Lucas Thanks! I didn't know that. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For MSVC users : my two cents specific answer:

I just faced, a difficult to identify, compilation error with Eigen. It was caused by the procedure describe [here - Finding Memory Leaks Using the CRT Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx), which consists of overriding the `new` operator to detect memory leaks with the following macro :

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
#else
    #define DBG_NEW new
#endif
```

This macro doesn't work with Eigen.

As soon as I removed it, the problem was solved.

I hope this may help you.